# QAbstractItemModel::data() is not called for all tree subitems

Tags: qt, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a `QAbstractItemModel`-derived class attached to a `QTreeView`.

Model implements 2 top-level rows and one of them has 3 sub-rows. Only first 2 sub-rows are displayed. If I add one “dummy” top-level row then everything is displayed.

I used `qDebug()` to print how many times `QTreeView` calls my `model::data()` and with what indexes (only `Qt::DisplayRole` cases are printed) and see that it is actually called 2 times for sub-rows instead of 3.

Of course, first suspicion is that my `model::rowCount()` is incorrect and makes `QTreeView` “think” that there are only 2 sub-rows. So here are `qDebug()` prints:

```
rowCount returning 3 for parent 0xbc6f70
…….
Qt::DisplayRole for row 0 ,column 0 pointer 0xbc6fc0 parent= 0xbc6f70
Qt::DisplayRole for row 1 ,column 0 pointer 0xbc7068 parent= 0xbc6f70
```

where 0xbc6f70 is:

- `parent.internalPointer()` in `model::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent)`
- `index.parent().internalPointer()` in `model::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role)`

So why is `model::data()` being called for row 0 and row 1 but not for row 2 if `model::rowCount()` returned 3 for index with `internalPointer() 0xbc6f70`?

Here is the code:

```
int Model_Tree::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
if (!parent.isValid())
{
    // This is 1st level
    qDebug() << "rowCount returning m_RowCount" << m_RowCount << "for !parent.isValid()" << parent.internalPointer() << "row" << parent.row() << "column" << parent.column();
    return m_RowCount;
}

int column = parent.column();
if(0 != column)
{
    qDebug() << "rowCount returning 0 for parent 0 != column (" << column << ")";
    return 0; // only item at 0th column can have children
}

const TreeItem* pTreeItem = (const TreeItem*)parent.internalPointer();
if (0 == pTreeItem)
{
    qDebug() << "rowCount returning 0 for parent 0==pTreeItem" << pTreeItem;
    return 0;
}

qDebug() << "rowCount returning " << pTreeItem->m_Children.size() << "for parent " << pTreeItem << "type:" << pTreeItem->m_type;
return pTreeItem->m_Children.size();
}

QVariant Model_Tree::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
if (!(index.isValid()))
{
    return QVariant();
}

switch (role)
{
case Qt::TextAlignmentRole:
    return Qt::AlignTop;
case Qt::DisplayRole:
    void* p = index.internalPointer();
    int column = index.column();
    int row = index.row();
    qDebug() << "Qt::DisplayRole for row " << row << ",column " << column << "pointer" << p << "parent=" << index.parent().internalPointer();
// .... the rest of Model_Tree::data implementation
}
```

and here is some qDebug() output:

```
rowCount returning  3 for parent  **0x122ee138** type: 0
....
Qt::DisplayRole for row  0 ,column  0 pointer 0x122ee168 parent= **0x122ee138**
Qt::DisplayRole for row  1 ,column  0 pointer 0x122ee198 parent= **0x122ee138**
```

note **0x122ee138** - this is "internalPointer" value for parent node that contains 3 children

here are index() and parent() implementations:

```
QModelIndex Model_Tree::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    void* p = 0;

    if (!parent.isValid())
    {
        // This is 1st level
        // we use our whole record

        if (row < m_RowCount)
        {
            const TreeItem& treeItem = *(m_pRootItem->m_Children.at(row));
            const LogRecord* pRecord = treeItem.m_pRecord;
            const LogRecord& record = *pRecord;
            if (column == 0)
            {
                p = (void*)&treeItem; // because createIndex() wants void* a 3rd parameter
            }
            else
            {
                const QList<QVariant>& fieldList = record.fieldList;
                if (column <= fieldList.size())
                {
                    const QVariant* pField = &(fieldList[column - 1]); // -1 Because we have extra column at left side
                    if ( (QMetaType::Type)(pField->type()) == QMetaType::QString )
                    {
                        //const QString *pString = static_cast<const QString*>(pField->data());
                        p = const_cast<void*>(pField->data());
                    }
                    if ( (QMetaType::Type)(pField->type()) == QMetaType::QStringList )
                    {
                        const QStringList *pStringList = static_cast<const QStringList*>(pField->data());
                        //const QString *pString =  &(pStringList->at(0)) ;
                        p = const_cast<void*>( static_cast<const void*>( &(pStringList->at(0)) ) );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //qDebug() << "Creating index: " << row << ", " << column << ", " << p;
        return createIndex(row, column, p);
    }

    if (0 != column)
    {
        //qDebug() << "Creating index: " << row << ", " << column << ", 0 -- if (0 != column)";
        return createIndex(row, column, (void*)0);
    }

    p = parent.internalPointer();

    const TreeItem* pTreeItem = (const TreeItem*)p;
    if (0 == pTreeItem)
    {
        //qDebug() << "Creating index: " << row << ", " << column << ", 0 -- if (0 == pTreeItem)";
        return createIndex(row, column, (void*)0);
    }

    if (row < pTreeItem->m_Children.size())
    {
        const TreeItem* pTreeSubItem = pTreeItem->m_Children.at(row).data();
        //qDebug() << "Creating subline index: " << row << ", " << column << ", " << (void*)pTreeSubItem << "parent: " << pTreeItem;
        return createIndex(row, column, (void*)pTreeSubItem);
    }

    //qDebug() << "Creating index: " << row << ", " << column << ", 0";
    return createIndex(row, column, (void*)0);
}

QModelIndex Model_Tree::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
    {
        QModelIndex qi;
        qDebug() << "Creating INVACHILD PARENT index: " << qi.row() << ", " << qi.column() << ", " << 0;
        return qi;
    }

    const TreeItem* pChildItem = static_cast<const TreeItem*>(index.internalPointer());
    if (0 == pChildItem)
    {
        QModelIndex qi;
        qDebug() << "Creating NOTREEITEM PARENT index: " << qi.row() << ", " << qi.column() << ", " << 0;
        return qi;
    }

    const TreeItem* pParentItem = pChildItem->m_pParent;
    if (0 == pParentItem)
    {
        QModelIndex qi;
        qDebug() << "Creating NOPARENT PARENT index: " << qi.row() << ", " << qi.column() << ", " << 0;
        return qi;
    }

    qDebug() << "Creating PARENT index: " << pChildItem->m_RecordNumber << ", " << 0 << ", " << pParentItem;
    return createIndex(pParentItem->m_RecordNumber, 0, (void*)pParentItem);
}

QVariant Model_Tree::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!(index.isValid()))
    {
        return QVariant();
    }

    switch (role)
    {
    case Qt::TextAlignmentRole:
        return Qt::AlignTop;
    case Qt::DisplayRole:
        void* pInternal = index.internalPointer();
        int column = index.column();
        int row = index.row();

        if (0 == column)
        qDebug() << "Qt::DisplayRole for row " << row << ",column " << column << "pointer" << pInternal << "parent=" << index.parent().internalPointer();

        if (0 == pInternal)
        {
            //qDebug() << "DR: internal pointer is 0";
            return QVariant();
        }

        if (0 == column)
        {
            const TreeItem* pTreeItem = static_cast<const TreeItem*>(pInternal);

            QString displayString;
            QTextStream(&displayString) << pTreeItem->m_LogLineNumber;

            if (pTreeItem->m_type == TreeItem::Subline)
            {
                QTextStream(&displayString) << " (" << row << "-th sub-line)"
                                            << " " << (*(pTreeItem->m_pSubline));
            }
            if (pTreeItem->m_type == TreeItem::Record)
            {
                if (pTreeItem->m_Children.size() > 0)
                {
                    QTextStream(&displayString) << " (" << rowCount(index)/*pTreeItem->m_Children.size()*/ << " sub-lines)";
                }
            }
            return displayString;
        }

        // for columns other than 0 index contains QString* as internal pointer
        const QString* pText = static_cast<const QString*>(pInternal);
        return *pText;
    }

    return QVariant();
}
```

[image]

Comment: show code, without it is hard to help

Comment: Thanks Marek. I have added relevant (IMO) parts of code (parent value 0x122ee138 is now not the same 0xbc6f70 as it was in first postings because it is from different run)

Comment: I think most crucial part of code is `QModelIndex Model_Tree::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const` and `QModelIndex Model_Tree::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const`. There is a good example: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-editabletreemodel-treemodel-cpp.html

Comment: Marek, I have added index() and parent() code and also data(). I also added screenshot to demo what is printed in the tree where 7 sub-items are expected under last item. Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Marek for trying to help me!

The problem was in my QSortFilterProxyModel-derived class that didn't take into account sub-items )))